# How to determine AppWindow is focused or not

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I hope make toggleAppWindow function, when app window is shown, hide it, when app window is hidden, show it, so I need a way to determine current app win is focused or unfocused

I use following code get app window

```
var win = chrome.app.window.get(id)
```

I see [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window), it doesn't help

**how to do it?**

Comment: What do you intend to do to "hide" it?

Comment: hide app window when app window is shown, show app window when app window is hidden

Comment: Focused and shown are different things. Which one do you want to know?